# Return nth element in a list - eloquent javascript 4.3

Tags: javascript

In the eloquent javascript book, exercise 4.3 is about building lists.  The question is 
"Write function nth which takes a list and a number and returns the element at the given position in the list, or undefined when there is no such element.

If you haven’t already, also write a recursive version of nth."

So here is their solution

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  var list = null;
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  return list;
}

function nth(list, n) {
  if (!list)
    return undefined;
  else if (n == 0)
    return list.value;
  else
    return nth(list.rest, n - 1);
}

console.log(nth(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]), 1));
// → 20
```

I don't understand how the `if (!list)` is checking if the nth value is exists.  It looks to me like it is checking if the list itself is false.

Any pointers on what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: You are right. It is not checking if the nth value exists. It is checking if the list exists.

Comment: @LeoFarmer it is recursive, and if list.rest returns tail of list, it will check on next iteration. btw, i wonder what is the structure of list ? `{rest: {rest: rest, value: 1}, value: 2}` ? if nth value does not exists it returns `undefined` as in task.

Comment: How is the empty list defined? What would you expect `nth(nil, 0)` or `nth({value:…, rest:nil}, 1)` to return?

Comment: I added some more code to the question to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

The `if(!list) {...` check is totally necessary in this and is checking if the num is in the list. If you look at the recursive part of the function `return nth(list.rest, num -1);` the `list.rest` part is drilling down into the sublists, and if you go far enough you are going to reach the tail end of the list which the `rest` property will reference `null`. So if the number you are putting in is longer than the items in the list you will hit the `!list` condition and return undefined.

I will show you the list that is getting passed originally into the challenge so you can see where the `rest:null`  is

`{ value: 10, rest: { value: 20, rest: { value: 30, rest: null } } }`

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

```
if (!list)
```

is shorthand for "if list is not null".

Comment: …and not undefined and not empty and not false and not zero and not not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "console.log(nth(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]), 1));", at the bottom try this:

```
console.log(nth(arrayToList([10]), 1));
```

Might be useful to understand.

Comment: Nice answer! Remember to use code formatting on your answers so that they look neater.